# How to change content of element's outerHTML with proper encoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using certain package for typewritting effect in React.js. It looks like this

```
     <Typewritter
         options={{
        cursor: null
            }}
         onInit={typewritter => {
        typewritter.typeString(`${createOpenTag().outerHTML}Welcome`).start();
}}
```

createOpenTag is function that returns span element

```
  const createOpenTag = () => {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("tag-color");

    span.innerHTML = "<";

    return span;
  };
```

I need to convert it to outerHtml then which gives me entire  element with its content, because I want to have this particular char "<" in different color. The problem is it works well when typing letters, but when it comes to chars like "<" it encodes it to `&lt;`

How to convert it properly ?

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox?

Comment: It is not the case. The content of the span element is set before reaching to outerHTML property. So no matter how I write createOpenTag function it is converted then to outerHTML:  `<span class=\"tag-color\">&amp;amp;lt;</span>` U can clone my repo from here https://github.com/flowbartek93/portfolio.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this package works like this. I made a little research on this package's github, and other people had the same issue. As for now I've just used custom fonts, to display char I want.